# Decomposing FDs to BCNF

Tags: database, decomposition

For the relationship R(A,B,C,D), I have the following FDs..

- AB->C
- BC->D
- CD->A
- AD->B

There's no obvious BCNF violation and when I take the closures I get..

- AB+=ABCD
- BC+=ABCD
- CD+=ABCD
- AD+=ABCD

My only thought is that I'm wrong in determining my closures but I've never seen a set of FDs like this so I'm not sure.  Can someone tell me if I did anything wrong or is this already in BCNF?

Comment: It's certainly a curious set of FD's.  Can you get AC and BD as candidate keys too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, you have BCNF when every arrow is an arrow out of a candidate key. I think your closures are right, and this is already in BCNF.